# How to create curve Container?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create the curve that shows in the image exactly like that but I don't know how I create it in Flutter.

I have created this by using container decoration like that:

```
child: Container(
  height: 250,
  width: double.infinity,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.red,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(400),
      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(400),
    )
  ),
),
```

But it didn't show me as I want.

Comment: you forgot include image.

Comment: Can you provide a picture so we can have an idea of what you need? Other than that seems that you might want to use ClipPath. See more here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html

Comment: thanks i solve this by using custom clipper